# Convert String (16 February 2022 20 h 50 min) into date-time format in Google Sheet

Tags: regex, datetime, google-sheets, spreadsheet, substitution

I am trying to convert a string into date format in Google Sheet. I've tried different formulas but failed. I guess REGEXMATCH may solve this or even Google Apps Script can also solve this. But I prefer formulas if possible. Please advise your valuable opinion.

I have the string in the following format:

> 16 February 2022 20 h 50 min

I want it converted as follows:

> 16/02/2022 20:50:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to convert it into true date:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(A1, " (h|min)", ), " ", ":", 4)*1
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

or directly:

```
=TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(A1, " (h|min)", ), " ", ":", 4)*1, "dd/mm/e hh:mm:ss")
```

[image]

Comment: I am really poor in Regex. How can I develop my regex knowledge?

Comment: What will be the 3rd permitter for REGEXREPLACE?
I get return a #VALUE! from your solution.

Comment: @AmirHossain you can leave 3rd parameter of regexreplace empty or use `""`. check the images posted in answer. after 2nd parameter there is a comma `,` and nothing after a comma

Comment: @Harun24HR all guides out there are old and poor including this one I started with https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax ppl recon https://regexr.com/ , https://regex101.com/ , https://regexone.com/ but google sheets regex is a bit different - limited so not everything can be learned there

Answer (score 2):

Give a try on below formula-

```
=TEXT(DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1," h ",":")," min",""))+TIMEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1," h ",":")," min","")),"dd/mm/e hh:mm:ss")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'll try this soon.